# 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples

Tags: python, django

Having an error when trying to set choices on model field. Here's the code:

```
TICKET = 'TICKET',
TICKET_HISTORY = 'TH'
TICKET_RATE = 'TR'
PASSWORD_CHANGE = 'PASS'
CONTENT = 'CN'

TYPE_CHOICES = [
    (TICKET, 'Ticket created'), (TICKET_HISTORY, 'Ticket changed'), (TICKET_RATE, 'Ticket rated'),
    (PASSWORD_CHANGE, 'Password changed'), (CONTENT, 'Added content')
]

type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=TICKET)
```

TYPE_CHOICES seems to be correct, can't understand where's the issue with it

Exception:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at    0x7f8acad18bf8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/userwoozer/work/tickets/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/userwoozer/work/tickets/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/userwoozer/work/tickets/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 425, in check
raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
main.Activity.type: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
```

Comment: Your `TICKET = 'TICKET',` has a trailing comma, so you wrap it in a singleton tuple. You should remove the training comma, so `TICKET = 'TICKET'`.

Comment: thank you, couldn't find it

Comment: you can make use of `pprint`, to pretty print the value. That makes it more clear :)

Comment: in tyle model field have to change `choices= TYPE_CHOICES.choices`

Answer (score 13):

Just remove `,` at line 1 in your code: `TICKET = 'TICKET',`

Answer (score 6):

***Just dropping this here thinking it might help someone**

In my case I was facing this issue while running the **makemigrations** command and had my choices defined like below,

```
ACTION_TYPE = (
    (RATE_ADVISOR, 'Rate Advisor')
)
```

I just put a comma at the end of the choice and my issue was resolved

```
ACTION_TYPE = (
    (RATE_ADVISOR, 'Rate Advisor'), #note this comma here
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that you have a col(,) after "TICKET" and that means you pass a tuple inside another one as you see!

```
TYPE_CHOICES = [
    ((TICKET), 'Ticket created'), (TICKET_HISTORY, 'Ticket changed'),
]
```

So this is was the problem
Actually, you can use something like this

```
class TYPE_CHOICES(models.TextChoices):
    TICKET = "TICKET", "Ticket created"

type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=TYPE_CHOICES.choices, 
    default=TYPE_CHOICES.TICKET)
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this error said that You are forget to put 2 values in one of the inner tuple. This usually happens when you insert bigger size values.

Answer:

1. Recheck your Inner Tuple Value.
2. One of them must include 1 value or more than 2 values i.e.
   greater than 3 or equal.

Answer (score 0):

[image]It work for me

```
oprator_list= ['GSM','CDMA','GSM/CDMA']
ALL_OP = sorted([(item, item) for item in oprator_list])

all_state = ['Andhra Pradesh','Arunachal Pradesh','Assam','Bihar','Delhi','Chhattisgarh','Goa','Gujarat','Haryana','Himachal Pradesh',
             'Jharkhand','Karnataka','Kerala','Madhya Pradesh','Maharashtra','Manipur','Meghalaya','Mizoram','Nagaland',
             'Odisha','Punjab','Rajasthan','Sikkim','Tamil Nadu','Telangana','Tripura','Uttarakhand','Uttar Pradesh','West Bengal']
ALL_ST = sorted([(item, item) for item in all_state])

class Oprators(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    oprator_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    oprator_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    oprator_type = models.TextField(choices=ALL_OP, blank=True, null=True)
    oprator_state = models.TextField(choices=ALL_ST, blank=True, null=True)
    # oprator_image = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

Comment: please add more explanation for others to understand your answer better

Answer (score 0):

Just do this :

```
Task_Status = ["OPEN", "WORKING", "DONE", "OVERDUE"]
Task_Status_Sorted = sorted([(item, item) for item in Task_Status])

class Task(models.Model):
     status = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="OPEN", choices=Task_Status_Sorted, blank=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('TICKET', 'Ticket created'), 
    ('TICKET_HISTORY', 'Ticket changed'), 
    ('TICKET_RATE', 'Ticket rated'),
    ('PASSWORD_CHANGE', 'Password changed'), 
    ('CONTENT', 'Added content')
)
```

Comment: Please format your code properly using "```" markdown symbol and also consider adding some word comment how/why your answer answers the question